# Execute a callback when any ajax request is done on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a js file (using jQuery) that am making ajax request. The thing is that i want to redirect to 'login' whenever the error.status == 401 (Unauthorized), but i dont want to do this everywhere there is an ajax call.

```
error: function(e){
            if(e.status == 401){
                notice(e.responseText+' Please <a href="/login">Login.</a>', 'error');
            }
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? The code you are showing is incomplete and is not relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Define a new function that does what you want and call it inside the error callback:

```
var errorFunction = function(responsetext) {
    notice(responsetext +' Please <a href="/login">Login.</a>', 'error');
}
```

then:

```
error: function(e){
    if(e.status == 401){
        errorFunction(e.responseText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or define errorFunction() to be exactly the same as the current error handler and then just say `error: errorFunction`

Answer (score 0):

You can use global `ajaxError()` and define conditions within it based on settings like url or special properties you can assign to any xhr object within specific requests in `beforeSend` callback

Example modified from [ajaxerror() docs](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/)

```
$( document ).ajaxError(function( event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError ) {
  if ( settings.url == "ajax/missing.html" ) {
    $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
    // do a redirect
    window.location = '/path/to/login';
  }
});
```